# Silverlight / C# image not found exception handling

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, exception

I am trying to handle the case where an image i am looking for does not exist - it should default to a stock-icon image.

i.e.:
-- when sampleimage = http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png (exists - it should return fine)
-- when sampleimage  = http://www.thisimagedoesnotexist.com/something.png (does not exist - it should go into the catch block)

Below is my code i am using - however it *never goes into the catch block when the image does not exist*. I am usin this in a Silverlight application. Any sugestions on how i can get this to work?

```
try
            {
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(sampleimage, UriKind.Absolute));
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryException)
            {
                sampleimage  = "defaulticon.jpg";
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(sampleimage, UriKind.Absolute));
            }
```

Comment: Added new code , please try once again

Answer (score 3):

try below code

**ADDED CODE FOR HANDLING URL NOT FOUND**

```
        Image image = new Image();
        string sampleimage = "http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png";

        Uri address;

        if (TryGetUriAddress(out address, sampleimage))
        {
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(address);

        }
        else
        {
            sampleimage = "defaulticon.jpg";
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(sampleimage, UriKind.Absolute));
        }



 private bool TryGetUriAddress(out Uri validAddress,string addressToCreate)
    {
        bool isValid = false;
        validAddress = null;
        try
        {

            WebClient sc = new WebClient();
            sc.DownloadData(addressToCreate);
            validAddress = new Uri(addressToCreate, UriKind.Absolute);
            isValid = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isValid = false;
        }

        return isValid;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i read that OutOfMemoryException is the exception thworn when an Image (using BitmapImage) is not found.

Comment: Update: with above code block you provided, it still doesnt work :(

Comment: Note: that this is a Silverlight web C# applicationError 1 'System.Net.WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'DownloadData' and no extension method 'DownloadData' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I meant to say: Note -- i am working on a Silverlight web project. Looks like the DownloadData is not avabilalbe in Silverlight projects.

Comment: You need to add System.Net namespace

Comment: yes - i have that is already included. Like i mentioned above, mine is a Silverlight web project and this method is not available in that context. Can you try New > Silverlight Web Project, and you will probably see the same issue i am running into.

Comment: DownloadData is not available in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

I expect Saurabh's solution to work. I am just suggesting an alternative for your approach.
Before creating the BitmapImage, try to get hold of a valid URI and then pass it to the BitmapImage constructor.

```
Uri sampleURI;
try{
 sampleURI = new Uri(sampleUriPath,UriKind.Absolute);
}catch(UriFormatException ufex)
{
 sampleURI = new Uri(defaultUriPath,UriKind.Absolute);
}
image.Source = new BitmapImage(sampleURI);
```

Comment: The defaultUriPath would only be used if sampleUriPath didn't parse as uri.  It could still be rubbish for all sorts of other reasons, like the host name doesn't exist or the resource doesn't exist, just constructing a Uri object doesn't test any of those conditions.  The Uri type its just a more structured way of dealing with a Uri string.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle this is to use the `ImageFailed` event:-

```
bool defaultAssigned = false;
Image image = new Image();
image.ImageFailed += (s, args) =>
{
   if (!defaultAssigned)
   {
       image.Source = new BitmapImage(defaultImageUri);
       bDefaultAssigned = true;
   }
}
image.Source = new BitmapImage(sampleImageUri);
```

Comment: Hi Anthony - thanks for the reply. Looks like this doesnt work either in my Silverlight project :( Note that the image i am trying to access is an image through http:// (not on the filesystem). And the above never goes into the ImageFailed block even if the image is not found on the web.

Comment: @Simba: you do actually add the image to the visual tree at some point right?  Silverlight will not attempt to fetch the image until you do.  I suggest you use a tool like Fiddler to watch what is actually being sent and received between client and server.

Comment: I've never been able to get the ImageFailed event to fire.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760690/handling-image-load-exception-gracefully.  I'm thinking there's an SL bug here somewhere.

Comment: @Ken:  I haven't tested the specific scenario outlined in that question, but I have tested what I've posted here and that works fine.